# Swarm mode: Inspect worker node's container on manager node

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I was wondering if it is possible to inspect a container running on a worker node from the manager node? The container was created via docker service create. From the manager node, I can get the task's service id (via docker service ps  and even the container id (via docker inspect ) My end goal is being able to find the container's ip address. Any help would be much appreciated!

Additional info:

Docker version 1.12.1

OS: CentOS Linxus 7

Comment: `docker inspect` claims to support tasks in addition to images and containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to get that yet. You're supposed to just forget about dealing with ip's and rely on resolving using dns names (service names).

If you really want though, you could create a script that does the following.

1. Get the tasks ID's and their node names for your service.

   ```
   docker service ps myservice
   ```

   That will return something like

   ```
   ID                         NAME   IMAGE       NODE        DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE           ERROR
   31cb7clxw3lfi1y6ko12edjys  foo.1  alpine:3.4  vmw-node03  Running        Running 30 minutes ago  
   9gkzs118txbc8a8gvla3bildq  foo.2  alpine:3.4  vmw-node01  Running        Running 30 minutes ago
   ```

   The service has two tasks running on different nodes.
2. Get the Container ID's for each task

   I'm just doing it for one task here

   ```
   docker inspect --format "{{.Status.ContainerStatus.ContainerID}}" 31cb7clxw3lfi1y6ko12edjys
   ```

   Which will return the container id for the task

   ```
   13a24dff4bd1f9351938b09d32db451406ed64b5f890f66f18fec12c611e9175
   ```
3. Get the Container IP

   ```
   docker $(docker-machine config vmw-node03) inspect --format "{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}" 13a24dff4bd1f9351938b09d32db451406ed64b5f890f66f18fec12c611e9175
   ```

   Which returns it

   ```
   172.17.0.2
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Is there any way I can do this without docker-machine? I have already created separate instances without Docker Machine

Comment: the `docker-machine config node` part is just to tell your docker client which docker daemon (node) to connect to. You can either ssh into the correct node and run `docker inspect  ...` or you can set your local environment with the proper DOCKER variables and run your docker client. Run `docker-machine config somenode` go get an idea of the env vars that need to be set.